# datepicker for multiple date fields

Tags: javascript, datepicker

My page consists of a form with multiple similar lines :

```
<form action="/plan" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input type = "hidden" value="283" name= "id-1" >
        <div class="col col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="deadline-283">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="description-283" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input type = "hidden" value="287" name= "id-2" >
        <div class="col col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="deadline-287”>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="description-287” >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input type = "hidden" value="295" name= "id-3" >
        <div class="col col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="deadline-295”>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="description-295” >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like to show a datepicker for each of the deadline fields (which are dates.
I played around with the JQuery datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker but can't figure out how to use it in this setup. (If you suggest another datepicker it must be localizable for Dutch and date form dd/MM/yyyy

Some extra info (maybe not directly related to the question but to give you the reason why this is build this way): the form is dynamically build using a leaf template from Vapor. So the number of the deadline-xxx and description-xxx is different for each row, but I can parse it in my backend using the value of the id-? (which is an index)

Comment: What can't you figure out? What do you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: To show the datepicker for each datefield (deadline)

Comment: Give each input a common `class="datepicker"` then one line initializes all `$(".datepicker").datepicker()`. http://plnkr.co/edit/SOhKyisOuGgfipNVUF3K?p=preview

Comment: great, perfect ! thx

Comment: When adding the code to my project I'm getting : 

    280:556 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (280:556)
    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLBodyElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at Object.simulate (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.c (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)

Comment: (I also had to add https: to these two lines:
<link data-require="jquery-ui@*" data-semver="1.11.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery-ui@*" data-semver="1.11.2" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> or I would get an error